# JMS listener in microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have one microservice which exposes rest endpoint to display billing data. In the same microservice, I have message listeners (around Max 50 and min 10 ) which listens to queue and process billing.  Is it a good practice to have message consumer in microservice as it will be long running.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have jms listeners in your microservices, count of listeners also really doesnt matter as long as you have your boundaries defined and these queues lie within those defined lines. 
As far as long running jobs are concerned, if no one is waiting on you it is ok as well.